# How to validate request with token in .net core 2.2 api using Open Id Connect

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

I have a .net core 2.2 api setup and deployed to Azure.  I have used OpenId Connect to handle the authentication using azure active directory single tenenat using the code below.  And the Authorize decorator on my controller.  Everything works and when I browse to my azure deployed api (myappname.azurewebsites.net) I get microsoft login prompt.  I'm able to then login and view my route data.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
        {
            auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            auth.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(opts =>
        {
            Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(opts);
            opts.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = ctx =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
            opts.Scope.Add("openid");
            opts.Scope.Add("profile");
            opts.Scope.Add("access_as_user");
        });
```

The problem is that when I have the Authorization turned on for my controller, I am not able to call it form my angular SPA client application.  I have successfully configured MSAL and my api calls are passing a token.  However, I get the following error:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/bit4f574-5968-4a40-049d-1c0dc2ca0513/oauth2/authorize?client_id=caor847f-dd19-4489-bef7-684803728c665&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapi.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20user_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637373859487758409.MzhhYTAoeiudtMTdlNS00NzgxLWJjMTQtNzM1YWE3NsdlkelasdNGYxMmQtMjZmYS00YmI2LTgwY2UtNDEwMTNhMWNkN2Zi&state=CfDJ8KCu3Hr4UOhLjOspjLNEh0VtJd4GNXqwdibjSiZf7FpUJOL0EDlFso0g0s_iOZHDNbP2aiHVfdzqJSmHkesd-bMjP6ThYva6AfZBa8UZcnGcwgo2ldlg4Fx9vmNVDuSlvHyTlHkd8yNndslkgoyHtfM4RMXamq1wny1J39BZRRATn1RdAsgaLgKP_QkxLaDCwgvdzjp3dKls5UVQE1j7MD6bcKR__1-VmfVKhROn1coQh7OJrea6Jni4jdV7e0wv70TVprGtseJFg8fyHg3KKW14xeX2orlkgls5aLe1uG0c5ehlapFXBirBSgFU3uqOWw0_iLeJUbTL8-HPooixynQRWe1WoiLnQuFYUu7Lx-usdlglvM4WvLfAyTZ5uQY_KsOtr08MxWRlQ5HHVk8Moe1k_N_3BCz8sdkgowwZEKsGiKd_iwcXgzxmgg&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0`

How can I fix this?  It seems like my api is redirecting the client request to the microsoft login, but I'm thinking the way this should work is that my api should validate the token in the request or the scopes and grant access without redirecting the request to a login.

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is to separate SPA OAuth entirely from API OAuth, with the following behaviours:

- SPA does the redirect handling and gets a token from the Authorization Server - this code is Javascript based and does not need a C# 'web back end'
- API validates tokens via the token signing public key of the Authorization Server - this code is C# based, which is a good language for API development
- Authorization Server is an out of the box component such as Azure AD, and you never code issuing of JWTs yourself (good to see you doing this already)

Many online articles I've seen mix up these concerns and can be very confusing to people who are new to OAuth technologies. So it's important to be clear about what you want from the end solution.

**API OAUTH CODE**

Your C# code should only need a few lines by default, starting by adding a package such as this one:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.8" />
```

The code to configure the API's security would then look something like this. Note that there is nothing about OpenIdConnect / web behaviour here.

```
private void ConfigureOAuthTokenValidation(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
                    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid";
                    options.Audience = "api://default";
                });
```

**REAL WORLD SAMPLE**

My .Net Core API solution has some stuff that may be of interest. These samples are quite advanced but enable you to run a local API and SPA that work together.

- [.Net Core Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/05/net-core-code-sample-overview/)
- [API Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore)
- [API Security Configuration Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/host/startup/Startup.cs)
- [SPA Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final)

The goal is to get the best end result for both API and SPA, so perhaps the above links will help you think about what that is in your case.

Comment: So the code I already had handled the authentication process to the api "app".  I've removed it and instead added the Jwt authentication snippet you suggested.  This now shows a 401 unauthorized when I hit my api.  And now my client error is only: `GET https://myapiappname.azurewebsites.net/api/items 401 (Unauthorized)`. Which is good cause it is not redirecting to the login anymore.  But how does the snippet you provided allow access based on tokens?  Is that something that still needs to be added?

Comment: I'm guessing that I still need to add the startup authorization code similar to what you have in the API Security Configuration Code link?

Comment: I'd recommend first getting familiar with the token claims and how the validation process works in terms of OAuth messages. My [In Memory Token Validation Page](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/azure-ad-api-token-validation/) has some notes on how you can verify your Azure access tokens using tools. Once you understand this you'll need to make your code do the equivalent thing. UseJwtBearer is the most standard option - and I would omit the audience check until you've got something working. It is possible also that you may need to google / set some extra options.

Comment: One more question, just for my personal edification. Can all this api authorization and scope stuff be handled strictly in Azure once the base api app is deployed to an azure app service?  I'm just curios and want to use that option if it exists as a way to learn azure in more depth.

Comment: No - it is the API's role to enforce authorization so it has to check these things. Azure just provides OAuth endpoints and issues tokens for you.

Comment: Got it.  I guess I thought this could be possible because I know for a fact that authentication can be totally configured through azure as I've already played around with that and got it working.  But then again I guess for an API that is not the recommended setup.